# Passing more values into hspec tests cases with Yesod

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, monads, yesod, hspec

I'm trying to enhance my current test fixtures with passing more than just foundation (of type `App`) into hspec test cases. In the example below I'm passing an additional Text value inside of a tuple (as `IO (App, Text)` ) as opposed to directly returning `IO App`

```
beforeOp :: IO (App, Text)
beforeOp = do
  settings <- loadAppSettings
    ["config/test-settings.yml", "config/settings.yml"]
    []
    ignoreEnv
  foundation <- makeFoundation settings
  wipeDB foundation
  setUpFixtures foundation
  return (foundation, "foo")

innerSpec :: SpecWith (App, Text)
innerSpec = do
  describe "stuff" $ do
    it "should work" $ do
      post MyRouteR
      statusIs 403

spec :: Spec
spec = before beforeOp innerSpec
```

I can't figure out how to correctly structure `innerSpec` in such a way that I can do my normal Yesod testing with functions such as `post`, `statusIs` etc, but also have the `Text` value be available to those specs for reading.

Without Yesod I can do something along the lines of the following:

```
innerSpec :: SpecWith (Int, Int)
innerSpec = do
  describe "stuff" $ do
    it "should work" $ \(x, y) -> do
      x `shouldBe` y
```

and it will build just fine, but I can't quite get the types right as soon as Yesod comes into the mix. Advice?

Comment: I think you need to use the `before` function from hspec to make this work, something like `\(x, y) -> before (return x) $ ...`